# How do I avoid repeated code when using useState hook in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have three places where I'm using the **useState** hook and I had to write it three times. I want to know if there is a way I could write once instead of having to repeat over again.

```
const Header = () => {
  const [btnOpen, setbtnOpen] = useState(false);
  const MobileNavigator = () => {
    setbtnOpen(!btnOpen);
  }
  const [dropDown, setdropDown] = useState(false);
  const dropdown = () => {
    setdropDown(!dropDown);
  }
  const [openSearchform, setSearchform] = useState(false);
  const formdown = () => {
    setSearchform(!openSearchform);
  }
```

Comment: You could create a factory pattern for useState, but this is probably better unless you have tons of similar hooks.

Comment: I would put this under the category of incidental duplication. These three lines are better left repeated, since they represent 3 independent states. Combining them may feel to be more DRY, but is really an anti-pattern unless the values are tightly coupled by nature.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HOC(higher order component) for reusing component logic

- [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)
- [medium article with example](https://medium.com/flexiple/introduction-to-higher-order-components-hoc-in-react-by-example-26bb2eb5b33c)